# Unsupported media type error while uploading a file (Restfull webservices with jersey, java in netbeans)

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I created a webservice in order to do file upload:

**The service:**

```
package services;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import com.sun.jersey.core.header.FormDataContentDisposition;
import com.sun.jersey.multipart.FormDataParam;

@Path("/file")
public class ServiceResource {

    @POST
    @Path("/upload")
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    public Response uploadFile(
        @FormDataParam("file") InputStream uploadedInputStream,
        @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileDetail) {

        String uploadedFileLocation = "c://" + fileDetail.getFileName();

        // save it
        writeToFile(uploadedInputStream, uploadedFileLocation);

        String output = "File uploaded to : " + uploadedFileLocation;

        return Response.status(200).entity(output).build();

    }

    // save uploaded file to new location
    private void writeToFile(InputStream uploadedInputStream,
        String uploadedFileLocation) {

        try {
            OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(
                    uploadedFileLocation));
            int read = 0;
            byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

            out = new FileOutputStream(new File(uploadedFileLocation));
            while ((read = uploadedInputStream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
                out.write(bytes, 0, read);
            }
            out.flush();
            out.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

I also have a ApplicationConfig.java file which was generated when I created the service:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

package services;

import java.util.Set;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;

/**
 *
 * @author odjansse
 */
@javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath("webresources")
public class ApplicationConfig extends Application {

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        Set<Class<?>> resources = new java.util.HashSet<>();
        addRestResourceClasses(resources);
        return resources;
    }

    /**
     * Do not modify addRestResourceClasses() method.
     * It is automatically populated with
     * all resources defined in the project.
     * If required, comment out calling this method in getClasses().
     */
    private void addRestResourceClasses(Set<Class<?>> resources) {
        resources.add(services.ServiceResource.class);
    }

}
```

Apart from this I also have my form:

```
<html>
<body>
    <h1>File Upload with Jersey</h1>

    <form action="webresources/file/upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

       <p>
        Select a file : <input type="file" name="file" size="45" />
       </p>

       <input type="submit" value="Upload It" />
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

When I surf to:

```
http://localhost:8084/FAServiceProvider/FileUpload.html I see the form.
```

Though when I select for example an image to upload and send it I see this error in my server log:

```
06-May-2014 16:21:30.460 SEVERE [http-nio-8084-exec-20] com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequest.getEntity A message body reader for Java class com.sun.jersey.multipart.FormDataMultiPart, and Java type class com.sun.jersey.multipart.FormDataMultiPart, and MIME media type multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryV1aiwpqrTLNkIK8R was not found.
The registered message body readers compatible with the MIME media type are:
*/* ->
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FormProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.StringProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.ByteArrayProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FileProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.InputStreamProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.DataSourceProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLJAXBElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.ReaderProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.DocumentProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.SourceProvider$StreamSourceReader
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.SourceProvider$SAXSourceReader
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.SourceProvider$DOMSourceReader
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONJAXBElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLListElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootObjectProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.EntityHolderReader
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONRootElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONListElementProvider$General
```

The HTTP status code I get is `415 Unsupported media`. Though I get this with all the files I try to upload.

The url it tries to post to is:

```
http://localhost:8084/FAServiceProvider/webresources/file/upload
```

My question is now, what am I doing wrong, why is this upload not working ?

Comment: What type of file are you uploading ?

Comment: I tried a .txt file, and image file, .mp3 file, .pdf file. All give the same error. I doubt it has to something with the file itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apperently I have to include the mimepull jar which can be downloaded here: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jvnet/mimepull/1.6

Comment: I am getting same problem, I tried using http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jvnet/mimepull/1.6 and still it dint get resolved. Can you check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43253206/unsupported-media-type-error-in-jersey-api