# Unsupported Media Type error in Jersey API

Tags: java, rest, maven, jersey, jersey-2.0

I have seen multiple answers on stackoverflow and yet unable to identify what is wrong with my pom.xml.
I have to upload files on the server, so I am using the modified code from  FormDataMultiPart of [this link](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/rest/jersey/jersey-file-upload-example/)

I have the code as:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

import org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.ContentDisposition;
import org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.FormDataBodyPart;
import org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.FormDataMultiPart;

@Path("/files")
public class JerseyFileUpload {

private static final String SERVER_UPLOAD_LOCATION_FOLDER = "E:/Upload_Files/";

@POST
@Path("/upload")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public Response uploadFile(FormDataMultiPart form) {

     FormDataBodyPart filePart = form.getField("file");

     ContentDisposition headerOfFilePart =  filePart.getContentDisposition();

     InputStream fileInputStream = filePart.getValueAs(InputStream.class);

     String filePath = SERVER_UPLOAD_LOCATION_FOLDER + headerOfFilePart.getFileName();

    // save the file to the server
    saveFile(fileInputStream, filePath);

    String output = "File saved to server location using FormDataMultiPart : " + filePath;

    return Response.status(200).entity(output).build();

}

// save uploaded file to a defined location on the server
private void saveFile(InputStream uploadedInputStream, String serverLocation) {

    try {
        OutputStream outpuStream = new FileOutputStream(new File(
                serverLocation));
        int read = 0;
        byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

        outpuStream = new FileOutputStream(new File(serverLocation));
        while ((read = uploadedInputStream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
            outpuStream.write(bytes, 0, read);
        }

        outpuStream.flush();
        outpuStream.close();

        uploadedInputStream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

 }
```

My pom.xlm is as

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>Photographer</groupId>
<artifactId>Assignment</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>Assignment</name>

<build>
    <finalName>Assignment</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
            <inherited>true</inherited>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
        <!-- use the following artifactId if you don't need servlet 2.x compatibility -->
        <!-- artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId -->
    </dependency>
    <!-- uncomment this to get JSON support-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
    </dependency>

   <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.18</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.media/jersey-media-multipart -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
        <version>2.25</version>
    </dependency>               

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
<properties>
    <jersey.version>2.16</jersey.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>
```

I am using Jersey Version 2.16, I am still getting "Unsupported Media Type", even though I am using the jersey-media-multipart version 2.25. Is there some issue due to the version? Or what is wrong with this pom.xml??

Thanks, would be grateful for any help.

Comment: can you use `@FormDataParam("file") InputStream fileInputStream,` in your `uploadFile ` method argument and check.

Comment: How?? Din't get it.. Instead of FormDataBodyPart i should use FormDataParam?

Comment: It din't work, I am getting error 500, "org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ModelValidationException: Validation of the application resource model has failed during application initialization."

Answer (score 1):

You still need to register the `MultiPartFeature` that comes with the `jersey-media-multipart`. The feature will register the providers needed to handle multipart requests. The error you're currently seeing is because there are no providers registered that can handle the `FormDataMultiPart`. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30656345/2587435) for a couple different ways of registering it